# How do I fix the Apache error "client denied by server configuration"?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, zend-framework

I am using cPanel and Apache, and I am seeing the following error in my `error_log`:

> [Wed Feb 02 09:06:04 2011] [error] [client 110.34.4.242] client
>   denied by server configuration: /home/websmart/public_html/.htaccess

My project is based on PHP 5.3 using the zend framework. My `.htaccess` file contains:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Can anyone tell me what causes this error and how should I alter my `.htaccess` file to resolve this?

my webhost manager picture [image]

Comment: do you have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: @Elzo Vaugi i dont know how to do this on server ... and also don't know how to check this on server.

Comment: check if you have a rewrite.conf in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled

Comment: @Elzo: if it's cPanel / WH, mod_rewrite is almost certainly on.

Comment: @Elzo can i do that throught cpanel or WHM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your options.  You must have

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

to enable per-directory rewrite rules.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule

You may be able to put the "Options +FollowSymLinks" directive in the same .htaccess file, if your server-level config allows it.  The server-level config must set the "AllowOverride" directive to "all" or it must contain "Options" or "Options=FollowSymLinks" to allow you  to do this.  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

So, at least try with this as your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

If that doesn't work, you'll need to dig up your server config and modify the options there.

Comment: +1 for dark reference in the manual

Comment: Ben i think you might be interested in my new Question http://serverfault.com/questions/230262/rewrite-rule-for-htaccess-not-working-for-php-file