# rewrite rule for .htaccess not working for php file

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

After few tries i found out that

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* index.php
```

was not working but

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* index.html
```

was working, what could be the possible reason? and how can i fix it?

Comment: Do you get the same error when requesting index.php without any rewrite rules set?

Comment: What happens when domain.com/text

Comment: for first case i get error Internal Server Error for second case i get routed to index.html file

Comment: Are u working on local?

Comment: sure that index.php is working or there's a bug?

Comment: @borayeris i am working on webhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try(loop free):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks your answer was certainly helpful, but could you please modify your code optimized for zend framework .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php
```

Comment: getting the same error